# Why is my Ruby or ADB network command very slow inside my docker container, but fine for the host?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6, docker, ruby

Recently, two unrelated commands started behaving very poorly inside a Docker container with host-networking:

Android adb took some 12 seconds to connect to another machine's adb server to use its emulators, and Ruby took over 2 minutes to connect to https://rubygems,org.

Both commands normally complete within a fraction of a second, and still do when executed on the container's host machine, or when executed against certain different target servers on the same network.

In particular

```
ruby -ropen-uri -e 'p open("https://rubygems.org").read'|od -ta |head -2
```

took 2m12 on Ruby 2.1.2 and timed out after a minute with Ruby 2.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

For the internal servers, someone had allocated IPv6 addresses for them, but not bothered to tell the machine about them, and ADB was working through three IPv6 timeouts before trying IPv4.

For the external addresses, the same someone had allowed DNS to return IPv6 addresses, even though our external router was dropping the packets - same basic principle with timing out with IPv6 before trying IPv4.

The obvious suggestion, turning off IPv6 for the host with the slow commands doesn't work because unfortunately Android ADB finds IPv6 logic in the OS and explodes when the OS says it's unavailable.

---

My colleague has just pointed out to me that /etc/gai.conf can be used to give IPv4 precedence.